# Best way to find a implementation of a interface by name

Tags: java

Wanted to know what is the best way find a implementation type, usually i use the code below for abstract classes when needed, but unfortunately you can't use static blocks in interfaces..

```
public interface RegionFactory {
    /** */
    HashMap<String, RegionFactory> FIND_BY_NAME = new HashMap<>();

    static { // cant have static blocks in interfaces...
        BY_NAME.put("default", new Default());
        BY_NAME.put("withTypes", new RegionFactoryWithTypes());
        BY_NAME.put("withoutTypes", new RegionFactoryWithoutTypes());
        BY_NAME.put("withBridges", new RegionFactoryWithBridges());
    }

    /** empty */
    void doRun(Region region);
}
```

Comment: How about `FIND_BY_NAME = Map.of(...);` ? [Map.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-)

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Please provide more information regarding as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @akortex A user can specify with a command what type of factory he wants to use for a region, so I need to find the implementation by a name to execute the method (#doRun).

Comment: It doesn't seem like this map should be inside your interface. It should be inside a class.

Comment: @khelwood What is your idea?

Comment: Whatever functionality you're trying to put inside this interface that requires this map, put it in a separate class instead.

Comment: @khelwood I had that idea, but I thought that just creating a class with a single use/method would not be a good idea but I will do, atleast it will look better.

Comment: @Treleaven https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle

Comment: @Treleaven check another recommended answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach here is not optimal. Why would you want to store the map of factory/types on the interface. This does not make much sense. Conversely, having a `factory` object that does not create any kind of objects seems semantically confusing.

Personally, I think that you need to revisit your code in the following manner:

1. Get rid of the `RegionFactory` interface and replace it with a `RegionStrategy` one that will expose a `doRun` method.
2. Create a `RegionStrategyFactory` that will store the map of strategy implementation along with their key. This will also expose a method for acquiring the appropriate strategy.

Based on all the above consider the following example:

1. Strategy interface:

```
public interface RegionStrategy {
    void doRun(Region region);
}
```

2. Example concrete implementation:

```
public class RegionStrategyWithBridges implements RegionStrategy {

    @Override
    public void doRun(Region region) {
        // Do something
    }

}
```

3. Factory method:

```
public class RegionStrategyFactory {

    private static final Map<String, Supplier<RegionStrategy>> FACTORY_CACHE = Map.of(
        "default", DefaultStrategy::new,
        "withTypes", RegionStrategyWithTypes::new,
        "withoutTypes", RegionStrategyWithoutTypes::new,
        "withBridges", RegionStrategyWithBridges::new
    );

    public static RegionStrategy getFactory(String factoryType) {
        return FACTORY_CACHE
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals(factoryType))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .findAny()
        .map(Supplier::get)
        .orElseThrow();
    }
```

Based on all the above, I think that organizing your code in such manner will be a better choice. Also I think you need to have a look at common design patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    Map<String, MyInterface> FIND_BY_NAME = Map.ofEntries(
            Map.entry("default", new Default())
    );

    void doRun();

    class Default implements MyInterface {
        @Override
        public void doRun() {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces should only define a contract (set of methods that must be supported by all implementations), while [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) should be responsible for creating the required implementation.

```
public interface RegionRunner {
  void doRun();
}

public class RegionRunnerFactory {
    
  public static RegionRunner build(String name) {
    switch(name) {
      case "withTypes":
        return new RegionFactoryWithTypes();
      case "withoutTypes":
        return new RegionFactoryWithoutTypes();
      case "withBridges":
        return new RegionFactoryWithBridges();
      default:
        return new Default();
    }
  }
}

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    RegionFactory.build("default").doRun();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from removing the implementation from the interface, I would suggest that you generify your approach so that each class holds its own name:

```
@NamedFactory(value = "withTypes")
public class RegionFactoryWithTypes implements RegionFactory {

    @Override
    public void doRun(Region region) {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

You would need to define the annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NamedFactory {
    String value();
}
```

Then your factory would reflectively find all the implementations and add them to your map with the defined name as key:

```
public class RegionStrategyFactory {

    private static final RegionStrategyFactory _instance = new RegionStrategyFactory();
    private Map<String, RegionFactory> factories = new HashMap<>();

    private RegionStrategyFactory() {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.package.of.factories");
        Set<Class<? extends RegionFactory>> factoryClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(RegionFactory.class);
        for (Class<? extends RegionFactory> factoryClass : factoryClasses) {
            NamedFactory annotation = factoryClass.getAnnotation(NamedFactory.class);
            String key = annotation == null ? factoryClass.getSimpleName() : annotation.value();
            factories.put(key, factoryClass.newInstance());
        }
    }
    
    public RegionStrategyFactory instance() {
        return _instance;
    }

    public RegionFactory getByName(String name) {
        return factories.get(name);
    }
}
```